# Middle mouse paste in jupyter through firefox on linux

Tags: firefox, mouse, jupyter, copy-and-paste, sagemath

I am running sagemath 9.8 installed from source containing jupyter_core 4.11.2 and jupyter_client 7.4.4. I access the sagemath notebook with it's jupyter instance in firefox 116.0.2 on an Ubuntu 22.04 machine. `The file $SAGE_ROOT/local/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.10.8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/notebook/static/components/codemirror/src/edit/main.js` reports that sagemath's codemirror version is 5.56.0. In firefox `about:config`, I do have `middlemouse.paste = True`.

I would like to enable middle-button paste in the jupyter notebook.

My understanding from an older [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42550138/highlight-to-select-and-middle-button-to-paste-in-jupyter-notebook) is that the middle mouse paste with jupyter with firefox should be working as long as the version of codemirror is 5.44.0 or later. So I am not sure why middle button paste is not working.  Are there other settings I need to change?